# How to get all sensor from a Supermicro JBOD via IPMI

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, supermicro

how can I get all sensors on a SM JBOD via IPMI? When I use the IPMIView from Supermicro I see a lot of them, some of these not, specialy PSU (PMBus) things like Temperature, Voltage, etc. I need this for monitoring this sensors also.

Can somebody tell me the command how to get this information also?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Read Zabbix documentation about LLD (low level discovery) and then create your Template.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy, first, zabbix dont support LLD for IPMI, second is, that i got more informations with IPMIView than ipmitool and thats the problem, how i get the other informations?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Zabbix isn't supporting LLD for IPMI hosts now. It will be done in the feature (only via `ipmitool`). But, you can write your  own script for LLD on Zabbix agent by using `SMCIPMITool` console program.  As example you can take my [Zabbix NTP servers monitoring template](https://github.com/mikhiv/zabbix-untp-peers).

Comment: ok, thanks for this hint, but still the question, how can I get the information that I got from IPMIView/SMCIPMITool? Use supermicro a closed source/secret protocol to get this informations?

Comment: No, the ipmi protocol is the same. Supermicro use own enterprise specific objects. Your script must read the output of `SMCIPMITool` command.